# Alternative for NegotiationAuthenticator class from JBoss EAP 6 in WildFly 10.1?

Tags: wildfly, jboss-eap-6, wildfly-10, spnego, authenticator

I was working on upgrading JBoss EAP 6 to WildFly 10.1. In our application we are using the SPNEGO authentication mechanism in `jboss-web.xml`.

We are using `org.jboss.security.negotiation.NegotiationAuthenticator` in JBoss but in WildFly this class is removed. I didn't find any alternative class or a way to implement a similar authentication mechanism.

What is the alternative for this?

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-web>
    <security-domain>dsds-security-domain</security-domain>
    <valve>
        <class-name>org.jboss.security.negotiation.NegotiationAuthenticator</class-name>
    </valve>
</jboss-web>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should remove the `<valve>` element completely from the `jboss-web.xml`. You don't specify an alternative in WildFly 10.x. The SPNEGO works out of the box.

[The authenticator](https://github.com/wildfly-security/jboss-negotiation/blob/3.0.3.Final/jboss-negotiation-common/src/main/java/org/jboss/security/negotiation/NegotiationMechanism.java) is registered by [Undertow integration](https://github.com/wildfly/wildfly/blob/10.1.0.Final/undertow/src/main/java/org/wildfly/extension/undertow/ServletContainerAdd.java#L121) part in WildFly.

It should even work in WildFly 10.1 without change in the `jboss-web.xml`. If you leave the `NegotiationAuthenticator` entry in the file You will see just a warning message in the server log.

The only important change you have to care about is the `<login-config>` part of `web.xml` deployment descriptor. Now the `SPNEGO` name is mandatory value in `<auth-method>`:

```xml
<login-config>
    <auth-method>SPNEGO</auth-method>
</login-config>
```